# Do strong embeddings always provide all the ultrafilters that exist?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be a strong cardinal. Then for each $\lambda\geq\kappa$ does there exist a $\mu>\lambda$ such that if $U$ is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\lambda$ and $j:V\rightarrow M,V_{\mu}\subseteq M,j(crit(j))>\mu$ then there is some $\alpha$ and $x\in V_{\alpha}$ so that the ultrafilter $\{R\subseteq V_{\alpha}|x\in j(R)\}$ is Rudin-Keisler equivalent to $U$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all we want is that for every measure $U$ there is a strongness
embedding with a seed for $U$, then the answer is yes. To see
this, suppose $\kappa$ is a strong cardinal, and let $U$ be any
$\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on some $\lambda$. Let $j_0:V\to
M_0$ be any $\mu$-strong embedding, so that the critical point of
$j_0$ is $\kappa$ and $V_\mu\subset M_0$ and $j_0(\kappa)>\mu$.
Now consider $j_0(U)$ inside $M_0$, which is a
$j_0(\kappa)$-complete ultrafilter on $j_0(\lambda)$. Let
$h:M_0\to M$ be the ultrafilter by $j_0(U)$ as computed inside
$M_0$, and let $j:V\to M$ be the composition $j=h\circ j_0$. Since
the critical point of $h$ is $j_0(\kappa)$, it follows that
$V_\mu\subset M$, and so the composition embedding is a strongness
embedding for $\kappa$. Let $x=[\text{id}]_{j_0(U)}$ be the
canonical seed for $j_0(U)$ via $h$, so that $X\in j_0(U)\iff x\in
h(X)$. It follows now easily that $$X\in U\iff j_0(X)\in
j_0(X)\iff x\in h(j_0(X))\iff x\in j(X),$$ which is what you
wanted.

**Update.** But your question asks for something much stronger:
you want *every* $\mu$-strongness embedding to have seeds for
every ultrafilter $U$.

Here is one easy way to see that this can fail. Suppose that
$\kappa$ is strong and also $\kappa^+$-supercompact. Let
$\lambda=\kappa^+$ and let $U$ be isomorphic to a
$\kappa^+$-supercompactness measure, that is, a normal fine
measure on $P_\kappa(\kappa^+)$.

Now suppose that $j:V\to M$ be a $\mu$-strongness embedding with
critical point $\kappa$, for some $\mu>\kappa$, and furthermore,
such that $j$ is an extender embedding (a direct limit of
ultrapowers on $\kappa$). It follows that $j$ is continuous at
$\kappa^+$, in the sense that $\sup(j''\kappa^+)=j(\kappa^+)$,
since every ordinal below $j(\kappa^+)$ is represented by a
function from $\kappa$ to $\kappa$.

I claim that $U$ is not generated by a seed via $j$ for such an
embedding. If it is, then by basic seed theory we get a factor
diagram $j_U:V\to M_U$ and $k:M_U\cong X\prec M$, with $j=k\circ
j_U$, where $j_U$ is the ultrapower by $U$, and
$X=\{j(f)(\alpha)\mid f:\kappa\to V\}$, where $\alpha$ is the seed
for $U$, meaning that $A\in U\iff
\alpha\in j(A)$.

Since $U$ is a $\kappa^+$-supercompactness embedding, it follows
that $j_U$ is not continuous at $\kappa^+$, in the sense that
$\sup j_U''\kappa^+<j_U(\kappa^+)$. From this, it follows that
$k\circ j_U$ also is not continuous at $\kappa^+$. That is, $j$ is
not continuous at $\kappa^+$, contradicting our earlier assertion
that is was. QED

Here is another counterexample with lower consistency strength.
Suppose that $\kappa$ is strong and there is a measurable cardinal
$\lambda>\kappa$ that is measurable. Let $U$ be a measure on
$\lambda$, that is, a $\lambda$-complete nonprincipal ultrafilter
on $\lambda$. In particular, it is also $\kappa$-complete. Suppose
$\mu>\lambda$ and $j:V\to M$ is a $\mu$-strongness extender
embedding for $\kappa$, so that $V_\mu\subset M$, the critical
point of $j$ is $\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)>\mu$. Since it is an
extender embedding, it follows that $j$ is discontinuous only at
ordinals of cofinality $\kappa$, and continuous at all other
ordinals. If $j$ had a seed generating $U$, then $j_U:V\to M_U$
would be a factor embedding, with $j=k\circ j_U$ for some
$k:M_U\to M$, and since $j_U$ is discontinuous at $\lambda$, this
means that $j$ also would be discontinuous at $\lambda$, contrary
to our earlier observation. So $U$ does not arise in your desired
manner via $j$. QED

Comment: This is good. It looks like you started off with a strongness embedding $j_{0}$ and modified it to obtain a strongness embedding $j$ which produces our desired ultrafilter. However, I am interested in whether one can just use the strongness embedding $j_{0}$ that we started off with rather than using another strongness embedding. The fine ultrafilters that one obtains from strongly compact cardinals have this universality property. Therefore, in particular, the supercompactness embeddings have this universality property, so I wonder if strongness embeddings have this universality property.

Comment: Ah, I see that is what you had asked---I had read your question as $\exists j$, but you wanted it for all $j$.  That seems likely too strong to me, but I'll think about it.

Comment: I have now posted a counterexample to that claim, assuming a little greater large cardinal consistency.